# Update values but it return error 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

i have tree tables in a DB with the following structure:

table 1: 4 rows - student_number, Name,sex and major

table 2: 4 rows - song_id, language,Type and Producer

table 3: 3 row - student_number, song_id and Score

i am trying to update all the scores in which the language is 'English' and is sand by 'male' student to'A'.

There are two row will return.
below is the sql i have tried to make this happen but returns MySQL error

> 1242 - subquery returns more then 1 row

```
Update table 3

set score='A'

where song_id=

(select song_id from song

where language='English')

AND

(select student_number from student

where sex='male'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `IN` instead of `=`

```
Update table3

set score='A'

where song_id in (

(select song_id from song

where language='English')

AND

(select student_number from student

where sex='male'));
```

Comment: Probably the same has to be done to the second subselect: `AND student_number IN (select student_number from student where sex='male'))`